# Prove or give a counterexample that the maximal solutions of an autonomous differential equation are global

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm not finding a counterexample or a proof that given a autonomous differential equation $y' = f(y)$ defined on a limited open set $U$ (i.e., a set with compact closure), then the maximal solutions are global, i.e., defined on $\mathbb{R}$. I suspect that this statement is false, however I could not find any counterexample.
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: what happens if the maximal solution necessarily blows up in finite time?

Comment: @Sam what do you mean by "what happens"?I think that the solution can't blow up since $y$ is limited by hypothesis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution does not blow-up (it remains bounded), but may not be defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$.

Consider consider the equation 
$$
y'=\frac{1}{\cos y},\quad y(0)=0,
$$
where the right hand side is defined on $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$.
The solution is $y=\arcsin x$, which is defined on $(-1,1)$. As $x\to\pm1$, $y$ does not blow-up, but the point $(x,y(x))$ converges to the boundary of the domain of definition of the equation, $\mathbb{R}\times(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$.